# Spark Creates Less Partitions Then minPartitions Argument on WholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing, partitioning

I have a folder which has 14 files in it. I run the spark-submit with 10 executors on a cluster, which has resource manager as yarn.

I create my first RDD as this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> files = sc.wholeTextFiles(folderPath.toString(), 10);
```

However, `files.getNumPartitions()`gives me 7 or 8, randomly. Then I do not use coalesce/repartition anywhere and I finish my DAG with 7-8 partitions.

As I know, we gave argument as the "minimum" number of partitions, so that why Spark divide my RDD to 7-8 partitions?

I also run the same program with 20 partitions and it gave me 11 partitions.

I have seen a topic here, but it was about "more" partitions, which did not help me at all.

Note: In the program, I read another folder which has 10 files, and Spark creates 10 partitions successfully. I run the above problematic transformation after this successful job is finished.

File sizes:
1)25.07 KB
2)46.61 KB
3)126.34 KB
4)158.15 KB
5)169.21 KB
6)16.03 KB
7)67.41 KB
8)60.84 KB
9)70.83 KB
10)87.94 KB
11)99.29 KB
12)120.58 KB
13)170.43 KB
14)183.87 KB

Files are on the HDFS, block sizes are 128MB, replication factor 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would have been more clear if we have size of each file. But code will not be wrong. I am adding this answer as per spark code base

- First off all, **maxSplitSize** will be calculated depends ***directory size*** and ***min partitions*** passed in `wholeTextFiles`

  ```
      def setMinPartitions(context: JobContext, minPartitions: Int) {
        val files = listStatus(context).asScala
        val totalLen = files.map(file => if (file.isDirectory) 0L else file.getLen).sum
        val maxSplitSize = Math.ceil(totalLen * 1.0 /
          (if (minPartitions == 0) 1 else minPartitions)).toLong
        super.setMaxSplitSize(maxSplitSize)
      }
      // file: WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala
  ```

  [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1055c94cdf072bfce5e36bb6552fe9b148bb9d17/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/input/WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala#L51)
- As per `maxSplitSize` splits(partitions in Spark) will be extracted from source.

  ```
      inputFormat.setMinPartitions(jobContext, minPartitions)
      val rawSplits = inputFormat.getSplits(jobContext).toArray // Here number of splits will be decides
      val result = new Array[Partition](rawSplits.size)
      for (i <- 0 until rawSplits.size) {
        result(i) = new NewHadoopPartition(id, i, rawSplits(i).asInstanceOf[InputSplit with Writable])
      }
      // file: WholeTextFileRDD.scala
  ```

  [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a9339db99f0620d4828eb903523be55dfbf2fb64/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/WholeTextFileRDD.scala#L41)

More information available at [`CombineFileInputFormat#getSplits`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/42a61a4fbc88303913c4681f0d40ffcc737e70b5/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java#L174) class on reading files and preparing splits.

> ### Note:
>
> I referred **Spark partitions as MapReduce splits** here, as Spark
>   borrowed input and output formatters from MapReduce

Comment: I'm providing size of the files in the question.